# How to implement in-app purchase in cocos2d android

Tags: in-app-purchase, cocos2d-android

I implemented a game using cocos2d android and it is almost getting done. I stuck at implementing in-app purchase for it. I searched all the way in google. but not found any clue to do it using cocos2d-android. Could any one help me out?